# Java Objects and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm relatively new to java and i'm wondering how to go about writing this set of code.

Currently I have a class to create an object for each name and number pairs from a list the user inputs

```
public class Data
{
    private String x;
    private int y;

 //Constructor, getters and setter methods ...
```

A number of objects is created from the user input. The objects should then be put in another class file that contains an array of the object

```
public static void Input ()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    int listLength = 20;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listLength; i++)
    {
        String userString = s.next();
        Int userInt = s.nextInt();
        Data d = new Data(userString, userInt);
        DataArray = //created objects need to be inputted to another class
     }

....

public class DataArray
{

    private Data[] arrayObjects; //unsure how to write the array
    private int count;

    public DataArray (Data inObject)
    {
         ....
```

Then I will need to use the newly constructed array and display it as list to the user. Which i am unsure on how to refer to said array from the class. From lookng around I have come across many other people use ArrayList<>. I would much rather attain the differnt elements from the arrays by using a count variable.

Comment: Since `List` (which `ArrayList` implements) contains a `.get(int index)` method, your statement about accessing via a count variable doesn't really make sense to me. Among the advantages of the `List` approach is the avoidance of allocating the array sizes, plus easier iteration.

Answer (score 0):

An array object already provides a `.length` attribute, so your DataArray class doesn't really add value over using a simple array.

```
public static Data[] Input () {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    int listLength = 20;
    Data[] dataArray = new Data[listLength]; // Define here
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listLength; i++) {
        String userString = s.next();
        int userInt = s.nextInt();
        Data d = new Data(userString, userInt);
        dataArray[i]=d; // Assign here
    }
    . . .
    return dataArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public getData(){
  arrayObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0;i<arrayObjects.lenght;i++){
     System.out.println(arrayObjects.get(i).getX();
  }
}
```